# Proof of coordinates of centre of conic without partial differentiation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, analytic-geometry

The centre of the conic represented by:

> $S \equiv ax^2+by^2+2hxy+2gx+2fy+c=0$ is represented by $(x,y)\equiv \left(\dfrac{hf-bg}{ab-h^2},\dfrac{gh-af}{ab-h^2}\right)$

I saw it's proof using partial differentiation. Is it possible to prove this without partial differentiation? If yes, how (I do not know partial differentiation therefore I am looking for a different method)?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(u,v)$ be the center of the conic. Let us transfer the origin to $(u,v)$. The new coordinates $(X,Y)$ are given by $X+u = x, Y+v = y$ and the transferred equation is 
$$a(X+u)^2 + b(Y+v)^2 + 2h(X+u)(Y+v) + 2g(X+u) +2f(Y+v) + c = 0$$
This equation should not have linear terms in $X, Y$. Thus equating the coefficients of $X, Y$ to zero, we get
\begin{align*}
2au + 2hv + 2g &= 0\\
2hu + 2bv + 2f &= 0
\end{align*}
Solving for $u, v$, we obtain the given expressions.

Comment: "This equation should not have linear terms" - How can we say this?

Comment: @samjoe For a central conic with center at the origin, if $(u,v)$ is any point on the conic, $(-u,-v)$ is also a point on the conic (since this is the reflection of $(u,v)$ at the center. If the equation is $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$, then there are infinitely many $(u,v)$ such that $gu+fv=0$. If $g \neq 0$ or $f \neq 0$, this would mean that infinitely many points on the line   $gx+fy=0$ are also on the conic, a contradiction unless the conic degenerates to a pair of lines.